# How to integrate Eclipse Portable with Java Portable?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, sdk, portable-applications

I recently downloaded **Eclipse Portable** to do some **Java Programming anywhere**. I also downloaded **Java Portable**.

How can I **integrate Java Portable with Eclipse Portable**?

I know that on the "installed" version of these two, I need to set up the **CLASSPATH, PATH** and **JAVA_HOME** variables in order to use the Java Compiler(javac.exe)

How can I set this up on a thumb drive? How can I **tell Eclipse to use my portable Java**?

Please help me, and if possible please be specific and detailed procedure-wise. I am planning to deploy these applications on **Windows XP/7** machines.

Any efforts to answer my question will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: [Portable Eclipse with JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18129626/3357935)

Answer (score 3):

The following instructions use the folder `/apps` as an example, but any folder should work.

1. Download and install [Eclipse Portable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/) to any folder. ([64 bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/) or [32 bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/files/x32%20Versions/Final%20Versions/))
2. Download and install the [Portable Java Runtime Environment](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable)

   - **For 64 bit users**: Install [Java Portable (64 bit)](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable_64) to `/../CommonFiles/Java64`
   - **For 32 bit users**: Install [Java Portable (32 bit)](https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable) to `/../CommonFiles/Java`
3. Open your Eclipse settings file `../EclipsePortable/App/Eclipse/eclipse.ini`
4. Set the `-vm` as your portable Java installation. (Must be placed before `-vmargs`)

For 32 bit

```
 -vm
 E:/Apps/CommonFiles/Java/bin/javaw.exe
```

For 64 bit

```
 -vm
 E:/Apps/CommonFiles/Java64/bin/javaw.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should install it from within the program itself. I followed [this post](https://portableapps.com/node/55342) by berny23 and it worked perfectly (nothing else worked).

> You just need the normal java runtime environment and not the
>   jdk:https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable After
>   putting the files into the jre folder do this:
>   - Run Eclipse Portable
>   - Go to "Help" -> "Install new software"
>   - Select your eclipse version by clicking the small arrow next to "Add"
>   - search for "java" in the search bar
>   - Tick "Eclipse Java Development Tools" and hit finished.
>   - after installation click on "restart eclipse"

Answer (score 0):

You need to set java compiler in eclipse from below path.

Eclipse -> Windows(one of the menu on top) -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler

Comment: So, I'll just browse through the location of my Java portable and search for the compiler? Do I still need to set up the class path, path and java_home? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yup.. you need set class path and java home then set java path in eclipse to compile your project

Comment: my Java is portable too, and I cannot just set the class path and java home on the computer that I will be using, since that we are only given guest accounts. Where and how will I set up those, using Notepad? I need an eclipse and java that can be deployed from a thumb drive. thanks.