# Eclipse and Java Runtime Environment Portable

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to run eclipse and java portable, for this i did the following steps:

1. Download and install Eclipse Portable
2. Download and install the Portable Java Runtime Environment
3. Open the Eclipse settings file ../EclipsePortable/App/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
4. Set the -vm as your portable Java installation at the beginning

Eclipse is running now, but when i want to add a new project, there is no Java Project.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try changing the perspective - `Windows > Perspective > Open Perspective > Java`

Comment: There is no Java available, just Debug, Resource (default) and Team Synchronization

Comment: Probably you haven't downloaded the right eclipse package, have you downloaded the "eclipse IDE for java development" from the eclipse download page ?

Comment: i downlaoded eclipse portable from this site https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-neon-portable/

Comment: Eclipse Neon (4.6) is a couple of years old and 8 releases behind. The current version is Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14). Would extracting a [ZIP package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) of the current version be an alternative for you? Instead of using `-vm` you can put an JRE or JDK into the subolder `jre`.

Comment: I dont get it, then i have to install it rght? I am not able to install something due missing admin rights

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60084775/8187149), you need to do below steps

- Go to "Help" -> "Install new software"
- Select your eclipse version by clicking the small arrow next to "Add"
- search for "java" in the search bar
- Tick "Eclipse Java Development Tools" and hit finished.
- after installation click on "restart eclipse"

Comment: Just thought answer would be relevant than the comment

Comment: thx a lot, i was trying, but got the message while installing: "An error occured while collecting items to be installed"

Comment: Post complete error description, check for "Show Error Log" link or "Details" button from where you got the above message. You can also try what howlger suggested, you need not run through all these if you download right eclipse package.

Comment: Im not able to copy the whole error message, but here is the beginning, somehow missing rights?

Comment: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Failed to transfer artifact packed: osgi.bundle,org.apiguardian,1.1.0.v20190826-0900.
Retry another mirror
HTTP Proxy Authentication Required: http://espejito.fder.edu.uy/eclipse/releases/2019-12/201912181000/plugins/org.apiguardian_1.1.0.v20190826-0900.jar.pack.gz
Proxy Authentication Required